# How to multiprocess from request to SQL (SQLite)

Tags: python, sqlite, python-requests, multiprocessing

So I want to make requests to an api, transform the data somewhat and upload it to an SQLite database. Since this is generally a slow process, especially when the api may take around 5 seconds per request, I'm looking to use multiprocessing, mainly to send at least one new request while processing the previous. However, I tried some things and found it a bit tricky with the upload to SQL not to lose anything.

Simplified code example:

```py
import sqlite3, requests
import pandas as pd
con = sqlite3.Connection('testDB')
cur = con.cursor()
urllist = [url1,url2,…urln]

def getData(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = pd.read_json(r.text)
    return data
def uploadData(row,cur,con):
    cur.execute(f"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test VALUES {row['valA']}, '{row['valB']}');")
    con.commit()
def dataLoop(url,cur,con):
    data = getData(url)
    data.apply(uploadData,cur=cur,con=con,axis=1)

for url in urllist: 
    dataLoop(url,cur,con)
```

So, conceptually, I would like to know which kind of multiprocessing to use, which modules would fit this and how to make sure not to lose data (making sure to only work on new data once the old data has been fully processed and uploaded).

Comment: How many URLs in your list roughly - let's call this `N`? How long to fetch them sequentially? How long to write `N` results from a list already fully fetched into SQLite if you do it all in one go?

Comment: I've been doing this for different small projects, the one I'm currently working on uses an api (so the url is technically the same) with 180 pages. Getting all the data takes about 12 mins, I just tried 18 pages; if I preload them and upload later it took about 60 secs for everything, doing it at the same time takes 130 secs. I wouldn't want to store all the data in the memory though, that's why I'm using an SQLite db.

Comment: I'm still none the wiser, sorry. I asked you how many URLs are in your list and you tell me 180 pages but I still don't know how many are in your list because I don't know how many URLs are on each of your 180 pages. You also don't explain why you don't want the data in memory - what's the objection? Thank you.

Comment: There's just one URL but 180 pages of it. In another project I worked with 16x20 URLs. The objection to storing it in memory is that I want it to be scalable. Also since I'm going to store it in a DB anyways, why not do it immediately?